# Pointer list c++

Tags: c++, list, pointers, iterator, std

The code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>
class A
{
    public: 
    void printHello(){std::cout << "hello";}
};
int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    std::list<A*> lista;
    lista.push_back(new A());
    for(std::list<A*>::iterator it=lista.begin();it!=lista.end();++it)
    {
        //how to get to printHello method?
        //it doesn't work
        it->printHello();       
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

This code doesn't work. My question is how to get to method 'printHello' by iterator it? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You want

```
(*it)->printHello();
```

as the `*it` returns the stored pointer `A*` and only then you can apply `->`.

Comment: Or simply `for (auto a : lista) { a->printHello(); }` on modern compilers.

Answer (score 2):

Just change following line

```
it->printHello();
```

to

```
(*it)->printHello();
```

The operator*() gives access to the contained data of the container, which in your case is a pointer. When not using pointers in containers, just using operator->() would work, too.

Answer (score 1):

De-referencing `it` will give you pointer to A, then you need to access the methods or data members.

So use :

`(*it)->printHello();`

Answer (score 1):

Let me expand on Daniel's answer.

When you stick an asterisk in front of a variable, it is called 'dereferencing'.  Used this way, the Asterisk is a 'Dereference Operator'.  To put it noob-ishly (I don't know what level of understanding you have offhand), `*pMyPointer` acts like it was the Object that the pMyPointer was pointing to.  If it was a Pointer to a Pointer, then the result is just the Pointer.

As an example, when you call a method on a pointer, you use the Into Operator `->`.

These two *often* do the same thing:

`pMyPointer->MyFunction();`

`(*pMyPointer).MyFunction();`

In the case of the C++ iterators, the Dereference Operator is overwritten to return the object stored in its position.  In this case, what is stored in its position is a pointer, so you still have to use `->` unless you stick another Dereference Operator in there.